# Get all <PRO>-Tags in different layers

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i got a XML Document like this:

```
<PUB>
   <PGR>
      <PGR>
         <PGR>
            <PRO>
            <PRO>
            <PRO>
         </PGR>
         <PRO>
         <PRO>
     ....
```

So the PRO tags are in different layers, but I want to access all PRO tags.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this question is tagged XSLT, you might want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//PRO"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PRO">
     <!-- enjoy PRO -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that differently from normal situations, the use of `.` in applying templates **here is relevant**. In fact, in this way we select all **PRO** elements starting from the current matching node (**PUB**), while:

```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//PRO"/>
```

will apply templates to all **PRO** elements matching from the document root whatever the current node is.

Comment: Did you know that `match="//PRO"` is equivalent to `match="PRO"` ? Also, there isn't any guarantee that the first offered alternative is going to be selected at all -- you havent provided the complete code. The same, to a lesser extent is valid for your second alternative. Always provide complete solutions.

Comment: @Dimitre I see, questions that might seem obvious, are not so sometime :D; I've tried to improve my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//PRO"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PRO">
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XPath pseudo-operator `//` isn't a "synonym" for `descendant::`. Please, read the exact definition in the W3C XPath 1.0 Recommendation, then correct your answer.

Comment: @Dimitre, I removed this statement, that is because correct explanation is in your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
//PRO
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that are named `PRO`.

**According to the [XPath 1.0 W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)**,

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

Therefore, the above XPath expression is equivalent to the longer:

`/descendant-or-self::node()/PRO`

**It is generally recommended whenever possible to avoid the use of the `//` pseudooperator** as it causes the complete XML document to be scanned. Whenever possible. use as much context as possible to construct a more specific XPath expression so that it can be evaluated more efficiently.

For example, if in a given XML document it is clear that the wanted element `c` can be selected using the XPath expression:

```
/a/b/c
```

use it and never use:

```
//c
```

The difference in execution speed sometimes be in the order of hundreds or thousands times.

**Alternatively, in XSLT use just template pattern matching** -- this might be the shortest transformation that accesses and processes all (and only) `PRO` elements in any XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="PRO">
  <!-- Your code here -->
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```